# why declared method is not on object's property list

Tags: javascript, class

I have created two objects .One is dog1 and other is dog2.They are created using constructor function and class respectively.Both of them has a `bark` method ,but when i view those two objects in the console the object created with class don't have the bark method on it.What is the reason for this? but i can access the bark method using `dog2.bark()`

[image]

```
<html>
<body>
<input type='button' value='bark' id='mydog' />
<input type='button' value='bark2' id='dog2'/>
<script>
var btn=document.getElementById('mydog');
var btn2=document.getElementById('dog2');
var dog1=new Dog1();
function Dog1(){
   this.bark=function(){
      console.log('wooff');
   }
}


console.log(dog1);
btn.addEventListener('click',function(e){

    dog1.bark();
});

class Dog2{

   constructor(){
      this.sound='wooff';
   }
   bark(){
      console.log(this.sound);
   }
}
var dog2=new Dog2();
console.log(dog2);
btn2.addEventListener('click',function(){
    dog2.bark();
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try expanding that `__proto__` property...

Comment: If you're already on chrome, try using `console.dir()` instead of `console.log()`.  The latter does in fact hide the `bark` method, but the former will reveal the `__proto__` property which will contain the `bark` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `class` syntax is syntactic sugar around the old-fashioned way of writing this:

```
function Dog2() {
    this.sound = 'woof';
}

Dog2.prototype.bark = function () {
    console.log(this.sound);
}
```

That's *prototypical inheritance*; you'll find the method on the object if you expand/log the `__proto__` property in the console. All instances of `Dog2` share the same `bark` method through their prototype; if you attach a new `bark` method to each `this`, the method will be "directly" on each object, but will also unnecessarily use more resources because you have multiple identical implementations of the same thing.